# Reversibility of uniqueness theorem

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, boundary-conditions

If we use uniqueness theorem then we know that if the boundary conditions and the charge distribution is same in 2 setups in a certain region then the electric field and potential in that region in both the setup are same.

What if we know that the electric field and potential of 2 setups have  same function and have same charge distribution, then can we conclude that the boundary conditions are also same for the 2 setups?

Comment: You should probably think a little bit about the definitions of the things you're talking about. The "function" already includes the boundary information.

Comment: Ok. I actually meant the function defining only the points inside the region, not on the surface.

Comment: In general, I think you can treat the area _outside_ the sources as though they were the same, but if you look _inside_ the source charge distribution, your answer will differ if the charge density does. This is a way of understanding Gauss's Law, from outside any arbitrary constant source charge distribution, you can treat it like a point charge at it's center with a charge equal to the total charge, as long as you only consider solutions outside the charge distribution.